# Issues after Hard Drive Failure - Used Mklink, Uninstalled/Reinstalled, Game won't launch

Tags: windows-10, hardware-failure, mklink

Ok quick background:

My system is set up ssd for os and some programs and hdd for secondary programs/storage.

I used mklink a while back to link the a game folder in C:\Program Data to a location on one of my hdd's. Well the hdd failed last week breaking the link. I just decided to uninstall and reinstall the game putting the game folder back @ C:\Program Data.

Now the game launcher will start, but the game itself will not launch. Nothing happens, well it does start the exe file I can see in the task manager. I have run the repair tool(The game has a repair tool) a few times, tried uninstall/reinstall and tried different locations for the game folder using the settings option in the launcher. I have tried to manually run the exe file also. Multiple reboots have taken place. I am at a loss of what to do? Any advice?

Is it possible that the game has left something in the registry that didn't get uninstalled after the link was severed?

Answer (score 0):

I would Try some Suggestions.

Clean Remove the game once again and remove anything associated with it. Try to to Remove the Registry keys Use Ccleaner. reboot and install again.

I cant post in comments but I was wondering what game you were trying to install again. That way I could better improve my answer.

Comment: Hey Thanks for the help, it was eve online.  Turned out there was some error with the launcher, may or may not have been related to the hard drive failure.  They had a launcher repair post on 1/5/16 I used that and it fixed my issues.